# jOOQ auto-generator is not running after liquibase update on doing mvn clean compile

Tags: spring-boot, maven, liquibase, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I want jOOQ to auto-generate code based on the liquibase schema xml file that I have provided (not on basis of db connection).
If I change something in liquibase xml file, the change reflects in the database, but I am not able the new auto-generated code.
I have to run mvn clean compile twice in order for jOOQ to understand the change.

The generator part of my pom.xml looks like this. Please help:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.16.3.xsd">
    <jdbc>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
        <user>${spring.datasource.username}</user>
        <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
    </jdbc>
    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase</name>
            <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
            <properties>

                <!-- Specify the classpath location of your XML, YAML, or JSON script. -->
                <property>
                    <key>scripts</key>
                    <value>liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml</value>
                </property>

                <!-- Whether you want to include liquibase tables in generated output

                     - false (default)
                     - true: includes DATABASECHANGELOG and DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK tables -->
                <property>
                    <key>includeLiquibaseTables</key>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>

                <!-- Properties prefixed "database." will be passed on to the liquibase.database.Database class
                     if a matching setter is found -->
               
                <!-- The property "changeLogParameters.contexts" will be passed on to the
                     liquibase.database.Database.update() call (jOOQ 3.13.2+).
                     See https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html -->
                <property>
                    <key>changeLogParameters.contexts</key>
                    <value>!test</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
        </database>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You cannot have both `LiquibaseDatabase` and `PostgresDatabase` in your config. There's only one allowed `<name/>` element

Comment: @LukasEder If I use only LiquibaseDatabase in <name/>, it says it cannot find liquibase properties file in the resources folder when it is present there. It is a multi-module project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem your question is about

By adding the `PostgresDatabase` in addition to the `LiquibaseDatabase`, you just override the `LiquibaseDatabase` configuration for that `<name/>` element. You can't specify multiple of those.

#### The problem you were trying to solve

Please look at the documentation for jOOQ's [`LiquibaseDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/). It mentions that the `scripts` property should describe a *classpath* location of your migration file, not a relative path location, e.g.

```xml
<!-- Specify the classpath location of your XML, YAML, or JSON script. -->
<property>
  <key>scripts</key>
  <value>/database.xml</value>
</property>
```

(Note the slash at the beginning). Starting from jOOQ 3.16.5, which addresses an incompatible change within Liquibase itself (see [#13031](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13031)), you can now use relative paths along with an additional `rootPath` specification, which is required since Liquibase 4.0:

```xml
<!-- Specify the root path, e.g. a path in your Maven directory layout -->
<property>
  <key>rootPath</key>
  <value>${basedir}/src/main/resources</value>
</property>
    
<!-- Specify the relative path location of your XML, YAML, or JSON script. -->
<property>
  <key>scripts</key>
  <value>database.xml</value>
</property>
```

#### More longterm solution using an actual database

While the `LiquibaseDatabase` can help speed things up when your database is simple, as soon as you're using vendor specific features (stored procedures, data types, etc.), that approach isn't viable anymore. Running your migration on an actual PostgreSQL database, and then generating code from that would be much better. [You could use testcontainers for that, as explained in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/).

Comment: Thanks for responding.
I do not have any vendor (postgres) specific use cases that H2 cannot suffice, so I can still go ahead with first approach.
I modified the configuration as you suggested (Please see Edit in question), still it is not able to generate jOOQ code in the specified folder, says [ERROR] azure/postgresql/TrackerAzureImpl.java: package ...tables does not exist, Also one warning: No schemata were loaded: Please check your connection settings... Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : {=[public]}

Comment: I followed this so far: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/
If there is some other github repository/some code where jOOQ auto generator generates code using liquibase schema, could you please share?

Comment: @DivyanshiMangal: If you edit your question like that, it's almost like a new question, and it will become very confusing both to answer your series of questions in a Q&A style, as well as for future visitors to reconstruct what steps you've made. I think your updated question would best be asked as a new question here on Stack Overflow, instead?

Comment: Makes sense. I have reverted the edit here and posted it as new question. 
 Your help is greatly appreciated.